# Convert Simple Excel Macro to Google Sheet Script

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script

The below macro automatically sorts the values in the A column (ignoring header row) in ascending order each time the sheet is selected (if it can update the sort in real time that would be even better).

I also have conditional formatting set up so that each row containing the values 1-6 in column A will be highlighted in yellow. If that can be integrated into the script, that would be amazing but I don't know if there is a way to do that.

Can someone assist me in converting this so I can move into Google Sheets?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you understand the logic, then you need to write it in the language Google uses. There is no automatic converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function onChange(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1') {
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: true })
  }
}
```

you will have to define a trigger on onChange function

[onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

[trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange)